# How can I create another website inside of Codeigniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using CI3 to creatge website and make a dome for my manager to check it which placed inside of another CI website as below directory

I hosting this website on Linux server.

This is directories:
first web: var/www/html/webiste_one
second web: var/www/html/website_one/website_demo (This is website used for demo)

But the finally I got error pages not found 404

and here is my .htaccess

```
# Set PHP Time Zone:
#SetEnv TZ America/New_York
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Option +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webiste_one/website_demo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Thanks you

Comment: If you're trying to make a test site or demo site, you shouldn't be making a "website in a website." You should have another host, in a separate directory completely. If you are on a localhost, this is simple enough to make as many domains as you want. If you are on a live hosted solution, most companies allow you to subdomain for free, so you can make something like demo.site.com and put your demo site there.

Comment: I know that but this company requirement I don't have another way to do because this company structure so messy

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] Extended answer.

It's possible to have multiple application with one codeigniter installation.

For example you want to create two applications "foo" and "bar"

```
applications/foo/
applications/foo/config/
applications/foo/controllers/
applications/foo/libraries/
applications/foo/models/
applications/foo/views/
applications/bar/
applications/bar/config/
applications/bar/controllers/
applications/bar/libraries/
applications/bar/models/
applications/bar/views/
```

Each application needs a seperate index.php file. Just change each  `$application_folder` to the correct path.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/managing_apps.html